Using AWS RDS with LoadRunner Ent. an option?
Anyone installed LRE using AWS RDS? I was going thru the installation guide for LRE2023r1 and noticed LRE is not supported with cloud managed database. I tried googling for some kind of answers other than company want to monopolize their cloud strategy.
Thanks
Can LRE be install on aws rds, regardless.

Why would you want to do this?   You want your test tools to be hardened against issues.   You don't want tool instability to reflect in tests as false application instability.
Install in a way not supported, then have issues, and you have deliberately created a support nightmare for you, your management, and the tool vendor.   No one is going to be happy with a "good luck, you have reached a limitation of support for installation in a not supported (nor tested) manner."  Vendors will not guarantee or warranty their software in such a model.
This does not just apply to LoadRunner, but any performance testing tool.   If your open source tool says it requires Java xx.yy or greater, don't give it anything other than it's requirement.   If it says it must run on linux, do not be surprised if you have a difference in behavior on a linux subsystem on windows.

Go figure. Oh, the joy of managing another MSSQL server.

Your choice.  FAFO.   I have used LoadRunner for three decades.  For support reasons alone I would never go near this.
